# Which is the fastest way to create a test database(with all data) from a production database which is quite big in size (400 GB)?

Tags: oracle, docker, database-replication, database-mirroring, database-view

I am a java person and not so much familiar with Oracle available features. Please help me.
The requirement is that, we are looking for some virtual(replica/mirror/view) database to be created from Production database just for testing purpose. Once we are done with executing all the automation test cases, delete the virtual database created. So are there any such concepts in Oracle ?

We are on Oracle 12c.
Many apps use same DB(its huge)

PS: We also use docker for deployment and also AWS.

Comment: rman backup and restore did it for me back in the day ref. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/backup.111/b28270/rcmcncpt.htm#BRADV002 can restore the backup in a PDB using their docker images https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase (might need to adapt you tablespace creation scripts for a Portable Database installation and customise the docker image build).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use Rman duplicate to duplicate the test database from production.
https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2
you can duplicate from backups or duplicate from active database

Answer (score 0):

You can probably ask your database admin to export the table space to a new test machine which has the same oracle version installed. May require If there are only very few tables, then you can spool your tables out and use sqlloader to load them to a test database ( you will need to manually create the structure of the tables in test environment before hand.

In both cases, you might want to scrub out the sensitive information as per your requirements and standards.